# What is a way to figure the pads from a datasheet where the part diagram leaves out dimensions?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, pad

I am trying to draw a footprint in Eagle ([datasheet PDF](http://www.goldiled.com/uploadfiles/2019/11/20191127174357820.pdf)).

This isn't the first time I had to draw a part without enough dimensions, but I'm wondering if there is an easier or more precise method. Previously, I assumed the drawing was to scale and used Microsoft Publisher:

- File > Options > Advanced. Then under Display, next to Show measurement in units of, select Centimeters.
- Paste the drawing into Publisher, draw a line, left click, Format AutoShape, Size and set a large border dimension (e.g., 3.8 cm).

[image]

This somewhat works for basic linear dimensions. For uniquely shaped pads (not in this example) I imported a bitmap from Paint. Is there a less complicated way if the pad diagram is not available?

---

Also, any idea what the two different connectors are for that part? The larger connector appears to be a [MOLEX 43650-0413](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/43650-0413?qs=GEJyObWCoZhCQnfLN51BHQ%3D%3D). The white/yellow connector I do not know. It has four SMT pads (similar to a squirrel track with wide front legs).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it "actually matters", contact the manufacturer and ask for mechanical drawings.

If it doesn't matter that much, do what you're doing (which is, roughly, what I would do for hobbyist applications), or as an alternative, import the footprint as an image directly into Eagle. I haven't tried this myself but there are [many tutorials](https://maker.pro/custom/tutorial/how-to-import-custom-images-into-autodesk-eagle).